# Sprout Forms issue: form not submitting

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

After recently discovering the logs for Sprout forms (located in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`) I have been studying them and debugging new forms that I am creating.

After integrating a form hook in my templates, I am getting an error: `A form submission failed because the user did not have Javascript enabled.` - but I do have Javascript enabled... it is prevalent on other parts of the page.

Any tips... ?

Comment: Do you have any captcha plugins installed?  Can you try disabling them.

Comment: I am using invisiblecaptcha by you guys, Sprout...

Comment: This is likely an Invisible Captcha bug.  Can you disable it and see if you can get things working?

Comment: Yes completely disabling the invisible Captcha allows the form to trigger the email to send. Previous to disabling it, I also had an error: `[info] [plugin] [Forced] A form submission failed the Duplicate Submission test.`

Comment: Adam, we're unable to recreate this bug.  Can you tell us more about what "after integrating a form hook in my templates" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Sprout invisible captcha fixed this.

Please let me know if there is an update to this fieldtype plugin to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are caching the page. You can't cache a sprout form. The csrf will be the same for all the users.